# Cross tab issues / Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am using SAP crystal report(version 13.0.8.1216) for VS2010.

I have made a cross tab which shows cost centers `income` month wise for one year.

```
                 jan         feb       mar
Costcenter1     10000        1000      1200

CostCenter2      120         1300      0
```

Similarly I have to show expense accordingly.

My two reports work fine separately but when i make one report, subreport of the other( as my selection criteria for both cross tabs is different even though they use same tables).

**The subreport cross tab doesnt not extends to the second page. Only data that can come in first page of the main report is shown .**

```
1. 'Keeping Object Together' is unchecked  ( for all sections and all reports)
2. Suppress is also off
```

Any ideas? I tried placing my subreport in different sections also.. nothing seems to work . 
Thanks

Comment: what is the issue... 2nd page of sub report is not extending to second page? or sun report is not visible at all?

Comment: Sub report is visible but  2nd page of sub report is not extending to second page. when i click on the subreport in the preview tab , it opens complete report extending to multiple pages but on the main report it only shows first page.

Comment: So the is data that should get on 2nd page is totally lost?

Comment: when i click on the subreport in the preview tab , it shows complete report extending to multiple pages but on the main report it only shows first page. Data is not lost because when i export the report to excel all data is present ( main report + subreport)

Comment: check whether you have `checked` the option `Can Grow` for sub report

Comment: Yes can grow is checked.

Comment: The aim is to show 2 crosstabs in one reprot with different selection criteria ( based on account codes) . One cross tab for expense and one for income . Since i was unable to add 2 cross tabs in one report with diff selection criteria i opted for sub report. Is there any other workaround. Thanks a lot by the way :)

Comment: your approach is correct of using sub report for 2 crosstabs but I guess your sub report in the report is creating issue... Or else oen thing in a single report take 2 sub reports for 2 cross tabs and keep main report free from both cross tabs just use the main report to host sub reports.

Comment: I tried that , than both reports just display their first pages.

Comment: I have no clue on this strange behaviour....

Comment: Crosstabs placed in the Subreport do not grow horizontally; this is a limitation in all versions of Crystal Reports. I found a work around though http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/541